# Bulk move content from one category to another - Drupal 7

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, importing-exporting

I have a lot of content that I've imported into Drupal 7.  Unfortunately it imported to the wrong category.  Is there a way in Drupal or drush to bulk move that content from one taxonomy term to another?  Or is it a simple matter of assigning the new taxonomy term to the content?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)? [How to batch assign taxonomy terms to nodes using Views Bulk Operations](http://www.webomelette.com/how-batch-assign-taxonomy-terms-nodes-using-views-bulk-operations) is a good blog post about how to accomplish this. Basically, make a view that displays the nodes you want to edit. Add a VBO field to this view (using the instructions in the above blog post) and then go to the page you created with the View to do bulk operations on the desired nodes.